# What is chaincode (Open Blockchain) and is it compatible with the EVM?

Tags: evm, openblockchain

What is [chaincode](https://github.com/openblockchain/obc-docs/blob/master/protocol-spec.md#33-chaincode) and is it compatible with the EVM?

Chaincode [FAQ says it supports smart contracts](https://github.com/openblockchain/obc-docs/blob/master/FAQ/chaincode_FAQ.md#does-obc-support-smart-contract) and can these contracts be deployed and function on the Ethereum blockchain?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seems to support Ethereum contract languages like Solidity.

> The first OBC-supported chaincode language is Golang, and support for JavaScript and Java is planned for 2016. Support for additional languages and the development of an OBC-specific templating language have been discussed, and more details will be released in the near future.

Quote from: [chaincode FAQ](https://github.com/openblockchain/obc-docs/blob/master/FAQ/chaincode_FAQ.md)

Answer (score 1):

Chaincode is arbitrary programs in a docker container that satisfies the chaincode interface. It is possible to run the EVM in chaincode, and then pass solidity contracts in and so on, but I don't think it's been done yet.